# Why is data not available for US treasury bonds on Interactive Brokers website?

Tags: bonds, government-bonds, interactive-brokers

I wanted to buy my first bond ever today, but when trying to get the prices for "US Treasuries" in the bond scanner page on *Interactive Brokers*, I was greeted with the following message:

[image: IB Warning]

Is this because treasury bonds are "released" by the US government once every so often, trading not being allowed in-between periods, OR is it bad UX from Interactive Brokers' end?

Comment: Have you tried again later ?

Comment: Yes, no update. But this is part of the question. It could be that the data is only available during US market hours.

Comment: It could also simply be some technical issues on IG's part.

Comment: Possibly. As mentioned, this is the very first time I want to purchase a bond, so I thought to post the question in case this is a known feature of the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used the Bond Scanner before and when I opened it just now, it populated immediately.  That may be because as you said, the data is only available during US market hours. Or not.   I'd suggest that you call tech support if it won't open for you now.

Edit: Here's the IB [Help page](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/tws/twsguide.htm#usersguidebook/technicalanalytics/bondscanners.htm?Highlight=bond%20scanner)